# One of the messages in .po file doesn't show up

Tags: multi-language

I've changed a file `wp-content/languages/pl_PL.po`

```
#: bfa_header.php
msgid "notice"
msgstr "napis"

msgid "Online Information Website"
msgstr "Internetowy Portal Informacyjny"

msgid "something"
msgstr "coś"
```

I've added the second pair. It works for another language, but doesn't work for this one. All other messages are working. What might be the problem?

Comment: When you say 'it works for another language', what do you mean, specifically?

Comment: It means that i have .po files for multiple languages and translation doesn't show up only for one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you may not be able to just add a pair to your .po file, without first adding it to the wordpress.pot file: http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress#gettext_files. You'll also need to compile your .po file into a .mo (Machine Object) file in order for your changes to take effect.

I'm not certain that will work, but it should be a good start.

Comment: Your post helped me find the problem. I didn't recompile the .mo file :) Your link covers that too. Expand the answer a bit please. I'll mark it accepted already

Comment: Great, glad it helped.  I edited accordingly.

Comment: **without first adding it to the wordpress.pot** --- is wrong. Just you need a `.po` file and then have it compiled to `.mo`.
 Though its a very old question but I am leaving the comment so that viewers can be helped who dont have a POT file but have a PO of another language can still move on. And also, you'd need a language switcher to trigger showing this new language (qTranslate plugin can be used for this too).